# How to pass MySQL data from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Could someone point me in the right direction on how I could go about allowing a user to click a link on a PHP While Loop created MySQL table and pass that records info to another page.  I've looked through all the similar questions and none answer mine.  I am new to this type of programming.

Ultimately what my ideal scenario would be is this:  Currently I have a list of data created with a While Loop.  I would like a user to be able to click a text link that says REPORT ERROR.  This in turn would take them to an error reporting form and populate a column of spans using getElementbyid... innerhtml.  I know how to populate data with PHP on the same page but going to a new page is a different story.

Also as a newbie to Stackoverflow too, am I able to hire someone to do certain things for me?

Comment: add a simple query string to url ...  `/path/to/error_report.php?issue=123` , validate the issue value before doing db query for the data. No, this is not a hiring board, see help center regarding that

Comment: SO is not a job posting site, no. You should give some sample data and sample output if possible for good results.

Comment: @charlietfl's option seems fine from what you say. But, you have tagged your question with javascript and jquery, you could have everything on one page and create a "pop-up form" of some sort that process everything on the same page, without needing to redirect anywhere

Comment: I had never considered a pop up form.  I will look into that.  Thank you.  I would also assume that is a lot safer of a choice then transferring a session elsewhere?  If I am saying that right in referring to sessions.

Comment: I don't think the activity is inherently more or less secure. It's *how* you handle that activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="yourpage.php?id='yourdata'&name='your another data'">pass data</a>`.

you can simply give the link of that page where you want to send your data and with a question mark you can pass whatever data you want to pass .if you want to pass multiple data use & between the data values. like below. i hope this will help you.